# Inconsistent line breaking in list environment

Tags: lists, line-breaking

The following test code

```
\documentclass[8pt]{article}
\usepackage{extsizes}
\usepackage{setspace}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setstretch{0.75}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
  \item[] 00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000  00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000  00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
  \item[] 000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000  00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000  00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
  \item[] 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000  00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000  00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
  \item[] 00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000  00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000  00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
  \item[] 000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000  00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000  00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
  \item[] 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000  00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000  00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
  \item[] 00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000  00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000  00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

...produces the following rendered output:

[image]

**NB:** The gray bar running along the right side of the picture above represents "the space beyond the page's right edge."  (In contrast, the page's *left* edge is well beyond the left edge of this picture.)

In the list above, each item consists of three runs of 0's, separated by two spaces between any two adjacent runs.

Could someone please explain why for the first four items, there is no linebreak between the first and second runs of zeros?

Is there a *general* way to ensure that line breaking for the first three items follows the same behavior as what is shown above for the last three items?  (By "general" here I mean solutions that do *not* require inserting an explicit "line break directive" (e.g. a `\\` or `\linebreak`) wherever LaTeX wherever to produce such line breaking on its own.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are telling TeX to justify the lines but it has no chance to succeed. Use `\raggedright` so it can break at any white space.

The lines are still overfull unless you use a smaller font but

[image]

```
\documentclass[8pt]{article}
\usepackage{extsizes}
\usepackage{setspace}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setstretch{0.75}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}\raggedright
  \item[] 00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000  00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000  00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
  \item[] 000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000  00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000  00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
  \item[] 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000  00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000  00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
  \item[] 00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000  00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000  00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
  \item[] 000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000  00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000  00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
  \item[] 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000  00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000  00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
  \item[] 00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000  00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000  00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you!  One thing I still cannot understand is that, in my original example, which makes no mention of `\raggedright` anywhere, the right edges of the 5th and 6th items *are ragged* (i.e. for each of these two items, the first line is significantly shorter than the remaining two).  I expected that the first lines of these two items would be stretched out (by adding a bit of space between the 0s) so that their right edges lined up with those of the following lines.

Comment: @kjo no. tex never justifies by adjusing inter-letter space, so it just fails to jusify here